# Music app on iphone resets track to start after a while

Tags: iphone, music

I'm listening to some audio lectures on my iPhone. I've noticed that after leaving a track paused for a while it will reset to the start of the track. For instance, I'll listen on the way in to work in the morning and when I go home in the evening the track is back to the start. I haven't listened to anything in between. It's annoying since these lectures are 30 - 40 minutes long and I have to note where I paused it to resume.

Is there a setting I need to change or an alternative app that maintains position when left paused?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7529728)

> I contacted Apple about this bug. It is not a bug. It is a deliberate
>   UX decision of a fascist UX designer. Restarting songs should be the
>   user's decision. Clearly somebody at Apple does not understand that UX
>   is all about the behavior of the end user. This makes me very angry.
>   Anger is the result of failed UX design. Clearly I could always
>   restart songs of I wanted to with the back button. I now have
>   absolutely no way to continue listening to music where I left off.
>   This decision fixed nothing. Sadly its only one of many many decisions
>   since 2008 that flies in the face of well thought out UX design in the
>   pursuit of "features".